# Understanding the ambiguating new declaration of function error

Tags: c++

I don't understand this error
here is a link to view the code online:

https://onlinegdb.com/rkirYvU_M

I am trying to add the names of the drivers, owners, and model to vectors, and we need to use pointers and files.

Here is my main file:

```
#include "person.h"
#include "car.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

std::vector <Person*>people;
std::vector <Car*> cars;

int main()
{
    bool done = false;

    Person person;

    while(! done)
    {
        std::cout << "\n Please enter the owners ";
        Person*prompt_info();
        std::cout << "\n Please enter the drivers ";
        Car*prompt_info();
        Car*set();
        Car*print();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the person.h file:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;


class Person
{

public:
    Person();
    std::string get_name();
    int get_age();
    void prompt_info();

private:
    std::string name;
    int age;


};

#endif
```

Here is the person.c++ file:

```
#include "person.h"

Person::Person()
{

}


void Person::prompt_info()
{

    std::cout << " name: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    std::cout << "enter their age: ";
    std::cin >> age;

}

std::string Person::get_name()
{

    return name;

}


int Person::get_age()
{
    return age;

}
```

Here is the car.h  file:

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"    
using namespace std;
class Car
{    
public:
    Car();
    std::string get_model();
    Person* get_owner();
    Person* get_driver();
    void print();
    void set(Person _owner,Person get_driver);
    void prompt_info();

private:
    std::string model;
    Person*  owner;
    Person* driver;
};
#endif
```

Comment: `Person*prompt_info();` whats this supposed to do? Thats a function declaration.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] that describes the error, focus on "Minimal". A multiple-file code example is not minimal. Also, please correct the typo in your question and find a better question title. See [ask].

Comment: To use an instance method of the Car class, you need a Car object and in main you don't have any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to understand this error.
>
> ```
> main.cpp:23:25: error: ambiguating new declaration of 'Car* prompt_info()'
>      Car*prompt_info();
>                      ^
> ```

You seem to be confusing function declarations with member functions. Just declare a `Person` object on the stack and call the method through it's object. Do the same for your `Car` object. You can use your objects like this.

```
while(! done)
{
    Person person;  ///< Person object named 'person'
    Car car;        ///< Car object named 'car'
    std::cout << "\n Please enter the owners ";
    person.prompt_info();
    std::cout << "\n Please enter the drivers ";
    car.prompt_info();
    car.set();
    car.print();
    // TODO do something with your objects (store to vector?)
    // next time through the loop your person and car will
    // get initialized all over again
}
return 0;
```

You will have to store your temporary objects before they go out of scope if you want to use them later.